# how to set expandable icon in same place

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to set expandable icons .(i.e) let us consider table there are so many rows ok
if you view one rows by clicking view button. [the view button should consists (+) sign as well as (-) this two sign will be in same place ok.] if you cilck view button the sign will be change automatically to (-).then if you click another row. the existing (-) sign will change as (+).now current row will be change as (-). if you clear this means.....

how to set both + icons and - icons in same place that all

Comment: Create two different css classes for expand and collaps. You can use a same DIV or SPAN and just change CSS Class name of that instead using javascript.

Comment: welcome to SO. Questions asked here should contain the code of what you've tried so far and an info at which point you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have following button

```
<input type="button" class="expand" onclick="MyAction(this)" />
```

Your css class will be

```
.expand
{
 background-image: (Path for Expand icon)
}

.collaps
{
 background-image: (Path for collaps icon)
}
```

and you will have javascript like following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MyAction(element)
{
  if(element.className =="expand")
 {
   // logic for collaps behavior
   element.className = "collaps";
 }
 else
{
   // logic for expand behavior
   element.className = "expand";
}
}
</script>
```

**You will need some more CSS tricks to fix and align the icon but i hope you can do that easily :)**

Comment: hi kd thanks for reply now im using mvc application can you send that code

Comment: The code i have posted will work in your MVC application. You can refer this code and make changes according to your need. Cheers :)

Comment: If this answer helped you then please mark it as answer and post new question for your doubt :) Cheers

Comment: now how to set alternative color for table using css. in my table a record  have two rows one is grid and another one to view the rows now i want to set color in grid view kindly help me please

Comment: There is no any direct way to do so.. you have to use certain logic to identify the occurence of row.. whether it is Even Or Odd counter and you have to create two different CSS classes for both colors. Then you can apply that